# Image is not saving on my public path - laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, visual-studio-code, frameworks, laravel-8

im trying to save a profile image on a register blade, the images are going to database with the name but couldn't be save on my public/imgs repository, so i can't even show on a view. Can someone help me to resolve this problem? the name of the image on my database is "foto".

**public function store**

```
public function store(StoreUpdatePost $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();

        if($request->foto('foto')->isValid()){
            $file = $request->foto->storeAs('public/users',$nameFile);
            $file = str_replace('public/','app/',$file);
            $data['foto'] = $file;
        }

        User::create($data);

        //foto upload
        if($request->hasFile('foto') && $request->file('foto')->isValid()){
            
            $requestFoto = $request->foto;
            
            $extension = $requestFoto->extension();

            $fotoName = md5($requestFoto->getClientOriginalName() . strtotime("now")) . "." . $extension;

            $request->foto->move(public_path('imgs\users'), $fotoName);

            $data->foto = $fotoName;

            $data->save();
        }

    }
```

VIEW REGISTER BLADE

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')


<div class="container"><!---->
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card" >
            <br>
            <div class="textocs">
               <h4>CADASTRE-SE</h4>

               </div>
<br><br>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" enctype=”multipart/form-data” action="{{ route('register') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Nome') }}</label>
                            
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>

                                @error('name')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror

                                <br>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-mail:') }}</label>
                           
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email">

                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                                <br>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Senha:') }}</label>
                            
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="new-password">

                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                                <br>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Redigite a senha:') }}</label>
                            
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
                            </div>
                            <br>
                        </div><br>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="cidade" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Cidade') }}</label>
                            
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="cidade" type="text" class="form-control @error('cidade') is-invalid @enderror" name="cidade" value="{{ old('cidade') }}" required autocomplete="cidade" autofocus>

                                @error('cidade')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror 

                                <br>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="numero" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Número') }}</label>
                            
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="numero" type="number" class="form-control @error('numero') is-invalid @enderror" name="numero" value="{{ old('numero') }}" required autocomplete="numero" autofocus>

                                @error('numero')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror

                                <br>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="foto" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Foto') }}</label>
                            
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label for="foto">Foto:</label>

                                <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="foto" >

                             
                                <br>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <br><br>
                        
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Cadastrar') }}
                                </button>
                           
                       
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

MIGRATION TO ADD FIELDS ON USERS TABLE

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AddCamposTableUsers extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        
            Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->string('cidade');
                $table->string('numero');
                $table->string('foto')->nullable();
            });
        
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            Schema::dropIfExists('users');
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you have two conditionals? `if($request->foto('foto')->isValid())` and then `if($request->hasFile('foto') && $request->file('foto')->isValid())`

Comment: Actually I forgot and i took it off now. I was trying to do this profile image with differents ways. But it didn't work in the same way... What could I do?

Comment: did you run ```php artisan storage:link``` ?

Comment: yes! the storage link was created

Comment: Are you sure that your conditions (`$request->hasFile('foto') && $request->file('foto')->isValid()`) passed?

Comment: how can i check?